# The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type PostDetail (Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have code in ArticleActivity  (Activity)

Trying implement to PostDetail (Fragment)
   findViewById(R.id.like).setOnClickListener( new ResultLikeListener( this,(TextView)findViewById(R.id.like), res ));

Please can you help me.

```
public class PostDetail extends Fragment{

    private int mId;
    TextView mTitle;
    WebView mWebView;
//  TextView mBody;



     private Tracker tracker;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }





    }



.............
}
```

Comment: do you have any rootView in your fragment's onCreateView().. use that rootview.findViewById() to get view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `@overide` the OnCrateView Method of fragment to get the id's of your widget like textview or edittext, whatever you want to. In oncreate view  you have to inflate your layout as you do in activity, as you set the setcontentview, but here in fragment you have to inflate your layoutview. The code is something like :

```
 public class PostDetail extends Fragment {
   TextView mTitle;
    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_VIEW,   null);
        mTitle= (TextView ) _view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);
       return view;
     }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_VIEW, container, false); ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use it like this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_fragnment, this, false);
TextView txtView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.like).setOnClickListener( new ResultLikeListener( this,(TextView)findViewById(R.id.like), res ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the rootView of the fragment from its onCreate function.

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.like).setOnClickListener( new ResultLikeListener( this,(TextView)findViewById(R.id.like), res ));
```